# Which Yochanan Kohen Godol is in Al Hanissim?

Tags: history, tefilla, chanuka, kohen-priest

In Al Hanissim we mention a Yochanan Kohen Gadol. Since there were several kohanim gedolim named Yochanan which one is this, historically?

Comment: Which what is what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not so straightforward to assume that the Yochanan Kohen Gadol of [(Ve')](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/al-hanisim-or-val-hanisim)Al Hanissim is the same one who became a Tzeduki. The Vilna Gaon ([Imrei Noam to Berachos 29a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14215&st=&pgnum=45)) distinguishes them (and Josephus' account supports this): the latter was Matisyahu's grandson; the former is obviously, from the wording of the prayer, Matisyahu's father.

Answer (score 6):

Yochanan Kohen Gadol served for 80 years and he became a Tzeduki in the end!

Per Abaye: Yanai Ha'Melech was Yochanan Kohen Gadol.

Per Rava: They were different people. Yanai was a Rasha from the beginning, Yochanan was initially a Tzadik.

Answer (score 0):

There are three options. The famous Yochanan kohein gadol was either the father of Matisyahu, or his son, or his grandson. http://www.torahmusings.com/2006/01/yohanan-high-priest/