# בימי מתתיהו בן יוחנן כהן גדול - who was the Kohain Gadol?

Tags: tefilla, history, chanuka, kohen-priest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bmei Matisyahu ben Yochnan Kohen Godol](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4354/bmei-matisyahu-ben-yochnan-kohen-godol)

> בימי מתתיהו בן יוחנן כהן גדול - In the days of Matisyahu ben Yochanan Kohain Gadol

--["Al Hanisim" prayer said on Chanuka](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/chanukah/article_cdo/aid/597182/jewish/Val-Hanissim.htm)

Who was the Kohain Gadol - Matisyahu or Yochanan? (sources please)